# Is there any way to transform a variable (let) to constant (const)?

Tags: variables, methods, rust, type-conversion, constants

Does Rust have a method to transform a variable declared as let to a constant?

I would like to initialize an array with the size defined by the variable (tam), as I couldn't, I initialized with the size 90000. Is there any way to do this initialization with the variable (tam)?

```
    //the variable tam receives an i32 that represents the size of the input and I would 
    //like to initialize an array with this size -> //let mut cities: [[i32; 2]; tam] = [[0; 2]; tam]; 

    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let filename = &args[1];
    let tam: &i32 = &args[2].parse::<i32>().unwrap();
    //let mut cities: [[i32; 2]; tam] = [[0; 2]; tam]; 
    let mut cities: [[i32; 2]; 90000] = [[0; 2]; 90000];
```

Comment: No. A `let` is evaluated at runtime, whereas a constant (and an array length) must be known at compile-time. Use a `Vec` instead, which is essentially a (heap-allocated) array with a length that is determined at runtime: `let mut cities: Vec<[i32; 2]> = vec![[0; 2]; (*tam).try_into().unwrap()];`.  The `.try_into().unwrap()` is required because the length of a `Vec` (as for an array) must be a `usize` and the `i32` of `tam` may be out of range (e.g. negative, for example): perhaps you meant to parse it as a `usize` instead?  The `*` is required because you borrowed the result of `.parse()`.

Comment: IOW: `let tam = args[2].parse::<usize>().unwrap(); let mut cities = vec![[0; 2]; tam];`

Comment: I think that what you want are called Variable Length Arrays (VLA), there is some [proposal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/unsized-locals.html#variable-length-arrays) for that, but nothing implemented yet.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to convert a variable to a `const` in Rust. Rust `consts` are more like a C `#define` than a variable, in that is in inlined, "copy-pasted", in all locations that uses it during compilation.

I would suggest making `cities` a `Vec` since that *is* something that you can dynamically size during runtime.